# JSON-simple. Правильная запись массива объектов

Tags: java, массивы, json

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "name");
obj.put("age", 100);

JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add("msg 1");
list.add("msg 2");
list.add("msg 3");

obj.put("messages", list);

try {

        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("test.json")) {
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
        }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.print(obj);
```

Получаю строку:

```
 {"name":"name","messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],"age":100}
```

А как можно вписать массив объектов?
Что бы получить строку следующего вида:

```
[{
"name": "name",
"messages": ["msg 1", "msg 2", "msg 3"],
"age": 100
}, {
"name": "name1",
"messages": ["msg 4", "msg 5", "msg 6"],
"age": 101
}]
```

Comment: Анналогично. Создать JSONArray куда добавить множество  obj, а потом получившийся JSONArray  добавить в новый JSONObject и с ним уже работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю перед первым объектом нужно создать массив

```
JSONArray listMain = new JSONArray();

JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "name");
obj.put("age", 100);

JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
list.add("msg 1");
list.add("msg 2");
list.add("msg 3");

obj1.put("messages", list1);
listMain.add(obj1);

JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "name 2");
obj.put("age", 101);

JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();
list2.add("msg 4");
list2.add("msg 5");
list2.add("msg 6");

obj2.put("messages", list2);

listMain.add(obj2);

System.out.print(listMain);
```

Comment: Да, это вариант. Но а если надо добавить неизвестное число объектов в массив? Через цикл. Вот что именно интересует.

Comment: А чем вам это мешает? Ну генерите ваши объеты в цикле, а не линейно, и добавляйте там же в список. В чем проблема?

Comment: Всё, всем спасибо. Пока пробовал уже ответили. Вопрос решён.